# How can I access hidden system files with R?

Tags: r, macos, sandbox

I am Mac User. Whenever I want to access Mail folder located in the `/Users/user_name/Library/Mail` folder; RStudio just ignores it and doesn't show any files.

```
setwd("/Users/user_name/Library/Mail")`

list.dirs("/Users/user_name/Library/Mail")
> character(0)

list.files("/Users/user_name/Library/Mail")
> character(0)
```

I understand that because of access to these files requires admin authorization, the R cannot access them. **Is there a way to grant admin access to R to access hidden system files?**

This question is [cross-posted](https://community.rstudio.com/t/accessing-hidden-library-folders-in-mac/17786) on RStudio Community forum two days ago. Unfortunately, I couldn't get a reply. That's why I asked here again.

**Edit:** Both of `list.files()` and `list.dirs()` return nothing.

Comment: Maybe `list.files` instead of `list.dirs` ?

Comment: You are asking several things together and it's not clear where your problem actually is. First, as already noticed, use `list.files`. Secondly, if you want to grant admin access to R, just run R as administrator. Check also the arguments `all.files` and `recursive` in `list.files`.

Comment: If ^^ worked, then you may want to post back to the RStudio Community forum as well.

Comment: This is strange:  I have no problem using `list.files("~/Library/Mail")`.  It shows me 9 files there.  (I'm still on 10.13.6 High Sierra, and my account is in the Admin group, but I didn't give any special permissions to R.)

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you. Both of list.files() and list.dirs() return nothing.

Comment: @nicola list.files() doesn't return any results either. I tried to run RStudio as admin. It didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Giving R and RStudio apps the Full Disk Access solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @user2554330 it's the protected (sandboxed) directories that are below the top dirs (`list.files()` doesn't automagically set `recursive = TRUE` where `list.dirs()` does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add both the R executable and RStudio executable (drag their icons) to the Full Disk Access element under the Privacy tab of System Preferences => Security & Privacy:

[image]

NOTE: I also have `R` and `Rscript` in there but the pane is too small to show them.

Also NOTE that I do see

```
nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 22 [9: Bad file descriptor]
```

in the `Console.app` on these attempts and my call to `list.dirs()` *appears* to hang but it's just taking a while b/c I have a ton of folders/files under there (thanks, gmail).

I'd try it incrementally with `recursive=FALSE` in `list.dirs()` until you've verified everything is working.

This [post](https://rud.is/b/2018/11/09/escaping-the-macos-10-14-mojave-sandbox-with-r-rstudio/) has some links that provide background on this new sandboxed filesystem behaviour.