# How to See Hidden Files in a File Dialog Using R?

Tags: r, file, dialog, rstudio

Using RStudio on our Linux server, I am attempting to display a file dialog in R that allows the user to see hidden files (files that begin with a period {.*} that are visible with ls -a).  I have tried the following **file.choose()** and **rstudioapi::selectFile()** with different options, but the hidden files remain hidden in the file dialog in each case:

```r
myHiddenFile1a <- file.choose()
myHiddenFile1b <- file.choose(new = TRUE)
myHiddenFile2a <- rstudioapi::selectFile()
myHiddenFile2b <- rstudioapi::selectFile(existing = FALSE)
myHiddenFile2c <- rstudioapi::selectFile(filter = ".*")
```

Comment: I think this is an OS thing, not something R controls. Outside of R, open up windows explorer (`Win-E`), under *View*, find and select "Hidden Items". I realize this doesn't control when you present this to other users (as their explorer configuration might differ), but it does suggest that it may not be up to the app.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will follow up with some colleagues who are more LINUX OS specialists to see what they say.  However, initially this idea seems contrary to the normal way of viewing hidden files in a file dialog.  Almost all file browsers have a menu with an option that allows viewing hidden files which leads me to think it is a setting in the file browser itself.  The `file.choose` file dialog does not offer any menus or options, so it may not be possible.  If that is the case, this sounds like a good feature to add.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223774/how-can-i-access-hidden-system-files-with-r